# How to show real server time on progress bar?

Tags: r, shiny

I try to add progress bar to my load (init) page. This page loads before all stuff is loaded on ui and server side. I have no idea how can I show real, current loading time on progress bar, which reflects progress made in the back end. The only thing I've found is to simulate server computation using `Sys.sleep()`. Is there any other way to solve it?
Below you can find reproducible example mimicking server computation (`for` loop on a server side):

```
library(shiny)
library(waiter)

moduleServer <- function(id, module) {
   callModule(module, id)
}

mod_ui <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   
   tagList(  
      
      url <- "https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/size/w2000/2020/04/w-qjCHPZbeXCQ-unsplash.jpg",
      
      use_waiter(),
      use_hostess(),
      waiter_preloader(image = url,
                       hostess_loader(
                          id = ns("loader"),
                          preset = "circle",
                          text_color = "white",
                          class = "label-center",
                          center_page = TRUE))
   )
}

# Server #
mod_server <- function(id){
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      hostess <- Hostess$new(ns("loader"))
      
      for(i in 1:10){
         Sys.sleep(runif(1) / 2)
         hostess$set(i * 10)
      }     
      waiter_hide()
   })

}

# App #
ui <- fluidPage(
   mod_ui("test_ui")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   mod_server("test_ui")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: the sleep simulates some real code is running and takes time. you can just replace the for loop with your own shiny code and add `hostess$set(xx)` many places along the server code to increase the progress and finally hide it afterward. Not very clear where you want to show the progress. If you can provide an example and indicate where/ which expression you want to show the progress, we can help you to add the progress bar.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like I need to simulate server computations. I showed an example in my code above. When I start my app I would like to show progress bar on load page (waiting for the server to end computations).